# How to test API calls (Twitter, Google) and procedural generation

Tags: node.js, testing, twitter, google-api, automated-tests

So I've written a twitter bot script that uses mostly API calls to the Twitter API and the Google API (http requests).

The bot:

1. generates some random phrases from local data (Text PCG)
2. calls google to get a related image
3. posts everything to twitter

If I'd wanted to test this bot automatically what'd be the best approach (best practice) to think about the test suite:

- Integration testing with a fake HTTP backend
- Unit tests for every API call faking some results for the actual HTTP calls
- Unit tests that get random data from the PCG modules and fail if said data is not in the spec for what the APIs need (probably unit test without determinism)
- Other

I'm working in node, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, this question feels quite broad, but you might be interested in [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) :-)

Comment: I'm asking about what's the best practice in this case. Thanks for the link, but isn't selenium about testing webpages? My project is just a script.

Comment: [blog on testing with mocha](https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-node-js-testing-and-tdd-right-node-js-at-scale/)